# How can i Retrieve Image from Json in Php

Tags: php, json

How can i retrieve Image from JSON as the image are stored in a folder. The name output name is working but did not show any image.
**PHP**

```
<?php 

$json_file = file_get_contents('file.json');

$array = json_decode($json_file, true); 


     foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

     echo $value['Name'];
     echo $value['Image'];

    }

?>
```

**JSON**

```
[{
     "Name": "AnyName"
    "Image": "img/bk.png"

}]
```

Comment: Please check before submitting that your question is formatted properly. I've formatted it for you now. Do still edit the question and explain where an image should be shown and how you are consuming that JSON.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen i want to only show the image on the display but the name is showing and the image is not showing

Comment: How are you trying to show it? JSON is just what you showed: text. What you do with it after is the important thing. What did you do? Nothing?

Comment: ECHO it in an `<img.....>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo '<img src="' . $value['Image'] . '" height="100%" width="100%">'
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a comma in your json, it should be:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "AnyName",
        "Image": "img/bk.png"
    }
]
```

Comment: That's probably just a typo here; `json_decode()` would have failed if that was the case.